Searching for different Factor levels on one factor while other factor stays the same in R
I have a problem in R, my dataset has different factors with different levels.
For example one is an ID and another is a Year of observation like this:



ID
year




6
2015


6
2015


6
2015


6
2015


6
2018


6
2018


6
2018


6
2018


6
2018


7
2015


7
2015


7
2015


7
2015


7
2015


8
2015


8
2015


8
2015


8
2021


8
2021



And I want to find out if (and which) ID´s have observations in different years. In the above example has my ID 6 observations in 2015 and 2018 and ID 8 observations in 2015 and 2021.
I`m sure I would be able to solve this problem with loops but I could imagine, that there is a more easy possibility to do that. I would prefere to stay in base R and not using packages.

Just do table().

This question is similar to: Create columns from factors and count. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. -- f it's not about counts we will find another dupe

aggregate could help
> transform(aggregate(. ~ ID, df, unique), inDiffYrs = lengths(year) > 1)
  ID       year inDiffYrs
1  6 2015, 2018      TRUE
2  7       2015     FALSE
3  8 2015, 2021      TRUE

data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L,
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L,
2015L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L,
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2021L, 2021L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))

